# Une selenium ide with selenium2 and phpunit

Tags: phpunit, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

How can i use selenium ide with selenium2 and phpunit?
Can someone give me some advise?

Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

General Steps:

1. Install the IDE.
2. Run and save a testcase through the IDE.
3. http://seleniumhq.org/download/
4. Unfortunately, seleniumide1.9 supports selenium2 commands with native language support for ruby, java,c#,python but not for php
5. Hence, you will have to use one of the open source libs as mentioned on the downloads page for php.

Answer (score 0):

There's a PHPUnit extension for this:

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium

But it lacks the documentation almost entirely.